# Append result of iteration in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am pretty new to python, i am using python 3 and have some difficulties to append the result of the iteration to the array, following is my chunk of my code:

```
A = np.random.randn(len(meas),numx)
lengthA = np.linspace(0,len(A[0])-1,num=len(A[0]),dtype=int)
anorm = []
for j in range(0,len(lengthA)):
      x_normed = A/A.max(axis=0)
      anorm[:,j] = A[:,j]*x_normed[j]
```

Is it necessary to append the new result to empty anom ? somehow the code always tell me that the list of the indices must be integer and not tuple. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a value to an array at index *n* via the `array[index] = value` syntax, the argument within the square brackets must be an integer. In your situation, `j` is an integer but `[:,j]` attempts to reference multiple indices within the array.

```
for j in range(0,len(lengthA)):
    x_normed = A/A.max(axis=0)
    anorm[j] = A[:,j]*x_normed[j]
```

As an aside, if you want your for loop to run for as many iterations as there are elements within `lengthA`, then you can simply do:

```
for j in lengthA:
    do stuff
```